# How to get url from a bitmap in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, url, android-bitmap

I have a bitmap and how can I get this image to url?

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

I got bitmap from url. I want this things reverse. I want a url.

Comment: `I got bitmap from url`. Well then you have an url. What are you asking for?

Comment: Because this url wants cookie. I read url with cookie and get image. But TileProvider doesn't support cookie. So I got images, bbox but not without cookie url. So.. I want to tiling wms on google map. So my base problem is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446270/setting-cookie-for-custom-tile-urls-in-google-maps-android-sdk

Comment: Dont understand. Your working code is the same as of TileProvider for cookies. So its supports cookies i would say.

Comment: But its not working. Its not tiling. Either swift

Comment: Can be. But why are you stating that TileProvider does not support cookies while their code is the same as yours? Investigate deeper please.

Comment: I made a juice of mango and Now I want mango from juice.
Sorry for this but I think this example will clear what type of question you are asking.

Comment: Ahahahahahha. But really this link working with cookie. I want to create url without cookie soo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Save the `Bitmap` to a file, using `compress()`.

Step #2: Upload the file to a server somewhere, for which you can derive the resulting URL.

Comment: Thanks. I have done step 1. But how can i do step 2 simply?

Comment: @Hilalkah: Ask whoever set up your server how you should upload the `Bitmap` to that server. There are many, many possible ways that this could be done, and the details of the Android side will depend upon the server implementation.